# How do I remove a particular string of text in one cell in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Given that the following is a single cell of data in Excel:

```
Name: Dina Anderson
Age: 34
Employment ID: A166X
Position: Clerk
Location: Genewood
```

How do I go about removing just one string in it, such as Employment ID? I tried using wildcard `*` but it would remove everything beyond that particular string. Also tried `?` but how do I make it work if the string can vary in length?

EDIT: Just to clarify I'd like to do this in formula.

Comment: Change `"Employment ID:*Position:"` to `"Position:"`? it would be a good thing to know if you are doing this in a formula, VBA, Pandas, etc..

Comment: I'm so sorry that you have to deal with a data set like this. You might be better off importing it in to a proper table format, dealing with it using normal methods, and then exporting whatever format it needs to be in elsewhere. The answer is that you're going to need to use VBA. Use the `instr` function to locate the text position: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/instr-function

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to do it through formula, try following formula:

=REPLACE(B3,FIND("Employment ID",B3),FIND("Position",B3)-FIND("Employment ID",B3),"")

Replace B3 with the cell in which your data is.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Excel 2016+ with the `TEXTJOIN` function, you can use this **array** formula.

- Create a valid XML from the contents of the cell by splitting it on the `lf` character `CHAR(10)`.
- Use an `xPath` which returns the nodes that do NOT contain `Employment ID:`

  - `//s[not(contains(.,'Employment ID:'))]`
- Rejoin the nodes using the `lf` as the delimiter.
- You will need to ensure the cell containing the formula has `wordwrap` turned on.

---

```
=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),TRUE,FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),"</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s[not(contains(.,'Employment ID:'))]"))
```

*To enter/confirm an **array formula**, hold down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>. If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces `{...}` around the formula seen in the formula bar.*

[image]

If you don't have the `TEXTJOIN` function, you can try this formula which locates the `Employment ID:` string and the subsequent `lf` character, and replaces with nothing.

```
=REPLACE(A1,FIND("Employment ID:",A1),FIND(CHAR(10),A1,FIND("Employment ID:",A1))-FIND("Employment ID:",A1)+1,"")
```